# How are large directory trees processed in using the Spark API?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm a new Spark user and I'm trying to process a large file set of XML files sitting on a HDFS file system. There are about 150k files, totalling about 28GB, on a "development" cluster of 1 machine (actually a VM).

The files are organised into a directory structure in HDFS such that there are about a hundred subdirectories under a single parent directory. Each "child" directory contains anything between a couple of hundred and a couple of thousand XML files.

My task is to parse each XML file, extract a few values using XPath expressions, and save the result to HBase. I'm trying to do this with Apache Spark, and I'm not having much luck. My problem appears to be a combination of the Spark API, and the way RDDs work. At this point it might be prudent to share some pseudocode to express what I'm trying to do:

```
RDD[String] filePaths = getAllFilePaths()
RDD[Map<String,String>] parsedFiles = filePaths.map((filePath) => {
    // Load the file denoted by filePath
    // Parse the file and apply XPath expressions
})
// After calling map() above, I should have an RDD[Map<String,String>] where
// the map is keyed by a "label" for an xpath expression, and the
// corresponding value is the result of the expression applied to the file
```

So, discounting the part where I write to HBase for a moment, lets focus on the above. I cannot load a file from within the RDD map() call.

I have tried this a number of different ways, and all have failed:

1. Using a [call](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) to `SparkContext.textFile("/my/path")` to load the file fails because `SparkContext` is not serializable
2. Using a [call](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to `FileSystem.open(path)` from the Hadoop API, where the `FileSystem` is instantiated outside the RDD fails because `FileSystem` is not serializable
3. Using a call to `FileSystem.open(path)` from the Hadoop API, where the `FileSystem` is instantiated *inside* the RDD fails because the program runs out of file handles.

Alternative approaches have included attempting to use `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles("/my/path/*")` so I don't have to do the file load from within the map() call, fails because the program runs out of memory. This is presumably because it loads the files eagerly.

Has anyone attempted anything similar in their own work, and if so, what approach did you use?

Comment: I think `wholeTextFiles` is the way to go. Just add more memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I don't have 28GB of memory to play with. And taking that approach would break as soon as I was handed a larger file set that was, say, 500GB instead of 28.

Comment: No, `wholeTextFiles` just needs enough memory to load the largest file. If you get more files, that's fine, you won't need more memory. (It loads 1 file at a time per executor thread. You can also limit the number of executor threads, so there is more memory per thread.)

Answer (score -1):

Try using a wildcard to read the whole directory.

`val errorCount = sc.textFile("hdfs://some-directory/*")`

Actually, spark can read a whole hfs directory, quote from spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)

> All of Spark’s file-based input methods, including textFile, support
>   running on directories, compressed files, and wildcards as well. For
>   example, you can use `textFile("/my/directory")`,
>   `textFile("/my/directory/*.txt")`, and `textFile("/my/directory/*.gz")`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had considered that, but that is about 28GB of data over 150,000 files - if the method eagerly loads the files into the RDD then  it won't fit in memory.

Comment: Can you separate these files into several batches based on their directory? I mean you can separate files into 5 or 8 input RDDs, each at a time. By the way, this isn't what RDD `map()` should do.

Comment: I guess I could, but that would have to be done programmatically. What do you mean by your comment about map()?

Comment: @Jon What you do is between RDDs, not within one RDD, so that's not what RDD's `map()` function can do.

Comment: `sc.textFile` will read all the files into a single RDD with one RDD line for each file line. You will have no way to know where each file starts and ends.